# Error updating ACL for bucket: Invalid argument

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create a container registry and add the service account with the `OWNER` role by changing the [`google_storage_bucket_acl`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket_acl).

According to the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_registry#attributes-reference), the name of that bucket can be accessed via `google_container_registry.<name>.id`.

```
resource "google_container_registry" "registry" {
  project  = var.project_id
  location = "EU"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_acl" "image_store_acl" {
  depends_on = [google_container_registry.registry]
  bucket = google_container_registry.registry.id
  role_entity = [
    "OWNER:${local.terraform_service_account}",
  ]
}
```

```
$terraform plan

..

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_storage_bucket_acl.image_store_acl will be created
  + resource "google_storage_bucket_acl" "image_store_acl" {
      + bucket      = "eu.artifacts.dev-00-ebcd.appspot.com"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + role_entity = [
          + "OWNER:terraform-service-account@dev-00-ebcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        ]
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

However, if I run `terraform apply`, the following error is what I get:

```
google_storage_bucket_acl.image_store_acl: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error updating ACL for bucket eu.artifacts.dev-00-ebcd.appspot.com: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid argument., invalid
│ 
│   with google_storage_bucket_acl.image_store_acl,
│   on docker.tf line 6, in resource "google_storage_bucket_acl" "image_store_acl":
│    6: resource "google_storage_bucket_acl" "image_store_acl" {
│ 
╵
```

Comment: It seems you mixed it with `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` resource.

Comment: @MarkoE Sorry, I am rather new to TF and using it with GCP. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The example you linked is for `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` and in your code snippet you are trying to set `google_storage_bucket_acl` resource. I was just wondering if that is what you want.

Comment: So, my goal here is to set a service account as writer or admin such that it's able to push images to the container registry. Perhaps I need to use `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` or, as you pointed out, `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` for this to work?

Comment: Not sure, but this is the doc you linked: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_registry#example-usage. In there, the example is for `google_storage_bucket_iam_member`.  :)

Comment: Things that happen when you're on tutorial-life-support I guess :D I'll see if I can make this work and post an answer if I managed to do it. Thanks :)